# Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Transform with key of "rotateY" must be a string: {"rotateY":6}

Tags: react-native, animation, hook, expo

I used the animation on the react-native expo project.

I was going to rotate and change the opacity to my component(View) whenever the props are changed.

But I could not reproduce this animation.

Even if I remove the rotate animation, It doesn't work for the opacity animation.

This is my error screen.

[image]

And this is my some code.

```
...
let rotateValue = new Animated.Value(0);
  let fadeValue = new Animated.Value(1);
const animationStart=()=>{
    return Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(rotateValue, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }),
      Animated.timing(fadeValue, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true
      })
    ]).start();
  };

  React.useEffect(()=> {
    animationStart();
  }, [spinInfoData]);

   .....

<Animated.View style={{
        transform: [
          {
            rotateY: rotateValue.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1],
              outputRange: [6, 0]
            })
          }
        ],
        opacity: fadeValue,
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        height: hp(spinSize),
        flexDirection: "row",
        marginTop: hp(spinSize / -6)
      }}>

     .......
```

Comment: Can you provide expo snack example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the bug about the red screen like this.

```
transform: [
   {
      rotateY: rotateValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['180deg', '0deg']
      })
    }
 ],
```

And please change your code for the reset the animation when props is changed like this.

```
const rotateValue = new useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
const saveRotateValue = rotateValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['180deg', '0deg']
  });

....
// change the props
React.useEffect(()=> {
    fadeValue.setValue(1); // reset the fade animation
    rotateValue.setValue(0); // reset the rotate animation
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(rotateValue, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }),
      Animated.timing(fadeValue, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true
      })
    ]).start();
  }, [spinInfoData]);

    .......

<Animated.View style={{
   transform: [
     {
        rotateY: saveRotateValue
     }
    ],
   opacity: saveOpacity,

   ......
```